# Trying to fetch data from a third-party API but only obtaining empty arrays

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, get

I'm currently trying to learn some back-end by myself and I have run through some problems when trying to make third-party API calls through my ASP.NET Core Web API. I'm trying to get the movie information from a TMDB API GET but although I manage to get the information as a string, when I try to deserialize it, it results in empty arrays.

I went through a couple of videos explaining different methods of making third party API calls and ended up using HttpClient method, and since I didn't exactly have a class established in order to save the data into, I deserialized it into a dynamic object.

```
namespace MoviesRouletteReactApp.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class MovieController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        //private const string API_KEY = ;
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetMoviesList()
        {
            var movie = new List<Result>();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?language=en-US&page=1");
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "BEARER TOKEN");
                var response = await client.GetAsync(client.BaseAddress);
                if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var stringResponse = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var dynamicResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringResponse);
                    return Ok(dynamicResult.results);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestException(response.ReasonPhrase);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is what I get as a result in Swagger when I try to execute the GET request:

```
[
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ],
  [
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      [
        [],
        [],
        []
      ]
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ],
    [
      []
    ]
  ]
]
```

By no means am I very knowledgeable currently and am mostly learning through trial and error, so any kind of feedback would be welcome.

Comment: If you make the request through a UI like PostMan, do you see the expected content in the response?

Comment: I haven't tried using Postman as I didn't want to create an account already having access to Swagger, but I would like to know if they differ by much

Comment: I'm guessing it's not serializing any properties because a dynamic object _doesn't_ define any properties. If you're using Netwonsoft, you could deserialize to `JObject` or `Dictionary<string, object>` instead

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, you can create the classes to deserialize into using the [Paste Special](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/paste-json-xml?view=vs-2022) option. If you're not using Visual Studio you can use a website, like this one [Convert Json to C# Classes Online](https://json2csharp.com/)

Comment: @AndrewWilliamson Yes I am using Newtonsoft, I did try to deserialize to JObject but it results in the same empty arrays, haven't tried the dictionary method, although I'm also new to it so I will have to investigate a bit.

Comment: @quaabaam I did try to create the class based off of the JSON data itself, although when I try to deserialize to the class it gives me an error when executing the GET request. Not sure if I can add the results on the question itself but I might once I get some free time to work on the code again.

Comment: @quaabaam Just realized I was deserializing to a property of the class rather than the Root class itself. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here
`var dynamicResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(stringResponse);`

Instead of deserialising your response into `dynamic`, create a Class in-line with the API output and deserialise into that.

As some people has pointed out `dynamic` doesn’t have any properties so you’re getting empty sort of array.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! Yep, this did the job, though I realized the problem was at my end as I was deserializing into a property from the Root class rather than the class itself.